# What's the Bash command recent files?

Tags: command-line, unix, bash, find

I want to find all files that are:

- recent
- do not end in .class
- no directories

This is what I have attempted but it is not working:

```
find . \( -atime -1 -a \! -type d -a \! -name '.class' \) -ls
```

I simplified it to this:

```
find . -atime -1 -ls
```

But it is still picking up things from January and earlier.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: `-a` (and) is implied so you can omit those (and the parentheses). You probably also want a "*" in the name spec: `\! -name '*.class'`

Comment: I see you've already done that here: http://superuser.com/questions/107201/how-can-i-script-making-a-backup-of-recently-modified-files-in-bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want either -mtime or -ctime.  -atime checks the access time, which includes accessing the file metadata.  So doing a ls (or a find -atime) will update the access time.  -mtime is the time the file contents were last modified and -ctime is the last time the "status" was changed, which I think is the file metadata (permissions, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Solutions use:

```
find . -ctime -1 -ls
```